# Inventor param value with '{' not parsing in Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I'm trying to collect all the user parameters from an Inventor assembly using Forge's Design Automation API. While trying to collect for a particular parameter with value having curly braces in it('{'), we get the below error. But while trying the same on Desktop inventor it works fine. Can someone explain?

The error
Processing failed: System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
[06/18/2023 07:07:05]    at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
[06/18/2023 07:07:05]    at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
[06/18/2023 07:07:05]    at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
[06/18/2023 07:07:05]    at System.Diagnostics.TraceListener.TraceEvent(TraceEventCache eventCache, String source, TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id, String format, Object[] args)
[06/18/2023 07:07:05]    at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.TraceEvent(TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id, String format, Object[] args)

Comment: It seems more like a possible issue regarding how you try to log the value the parameter which is using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format and where "{}" has a special meaning